# How to use boost.asio to exchange data back and forth btw client and server?

Tags: boost, boost-asio, asio

I implemented two simple client and server example, but it does not work. Both client and server just freeze without any messages printed.

client.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
std::string raw_ip = "127.0.0.1";
int port = 3333;
try
  {
    asio::ip::tcp::endpoint
      ep(asio::ip::address::from_string(raw_ip), port);
    asio::io_service ios;
    asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(ios, ep.protocol());
    sock.connect(ep);

    asio::streambuf request;
    std::ostream request_stream(&request);
    request_stream << "request from clinet\n";
    asio::streambuf response;
    asio::read_until(sock, response, "\n");
    std::istream response_stream(&response);
    std::cout << response_stream.rdbuf() << std::endl;
  }
  catch(system::system_error &e)
  {
    std::cout << "Encounter error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    return e.code().value();
  }
}
```

server.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  std::string raw_ip="127.0.0.1";
  int port=3333;
  try
  {
    asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep(asio::ip::address_v4::any(),port);
    asio::io_service ios;
    asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(ios, ep);
    acceptor.listen();
    asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(ios);
    acceptor.accept(sock);
    asio::streambuf request;
    asio::read_until(sock, request, "\n");
    std::istream request_stream(&request);
    std::cout << request_stream.rdbuf() << std::endl;

    asio::streambuf response;
    std::ostream response_stream(&response);
    response_stream << "response from server\n";
  }
  catch(system::system_error &e)
  {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Also I am wondering the best way to transfer a large amount of data to/from socket, how do we tell socket that I am done writing data to socket? And how do we know that we have read the last byte of data from socket? Thanks.

Comment: Send some metadata as well - i.e. tell the other side how much data to expect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the blocking function 'ios.run()`in both the client and server to animate`boost::io_service`.  In any case, I don't think your app will produce anything usable as is.  You should try and use one of the asio examples as a starting point.

The TCP blocking echo client/server example should be a good starting point for what you want to do.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/blocking_tcp_echo_client.cpp

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp

On a TCP connection, you can use a single asio buffer to ensure all of the data is sent.  But you should send a message beforehand to the client so it knows how much data it should expect to receive.

Comment: Thanks, the tcp echo examples really gives many insights. I realize that there are several ways to tell the other side that I am done writing data to the socket, 1, send a tcp message (not sure how to do that in asio, i guess this was what I asked) 2, close the socket 3 define a rule btw client and server.

Comment: The examples send TCP messages back and forth.